# My IDE is giving me an error on a simple Hibernate project

Tags: hibernate

The error is (The project was not built due to "Could not delete 'G:\Databases\Hibernate\My Project\HibernateDB1\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent). I am trying to learn a simple hibernate project on Eclipse IDE using MySQL database. The program ran correctly the first time. But after that when i tried editing the .cfg.xml file of the project, it gives me this error. What is it and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers to help you :

- You might be on the path ``G:\Databases\Hibernate\My Project\HibernateDB1\bin` from some command prompt
- You shouldn't be editing any filee at `G:\Databases\Hibernate\My Project\HibernateDB1\bin` because this is the target location of build and would be overwritten every time project is build.

Comment: Actually i am not. I am just trying to run the application from Eclipse IDE. I edited the cfg file in my Project src folder after which i am getting this error.

Comment: Manually delete the files from location `G:\Databases\Hibernate\My Project\HibernateDB1\bin`

Comment: Deleting the contents of bin after closing down the IDE sure helped. But it again happened after i ran the application once. What is the problem? Is my IDE causing it?

Comment: try this option  : "Clean" and uncheck "Build Automatically" from eclipse menu.

Comment: Correction to the previous comment : Use Project->Clean. Uncheck Start Build Immediately.